# How to write this query compatible with oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am facing issue to convert the sql  query  to oracle .Actually i am new to oracle db.

```
 SELECT TI1.FOLDERRSN, DBO.F_OPENTAX_PROPERTYROLL_FOLDER(TI1.FOLDERRSN) ROLL,
    TI1.DUEDATE DUEDATE, TI1.YEARFORBILLING,(TI1.SUMDUETAX + TI1.SUMPAIDTAX + TI1.SUMDUEPENALTY + TI1.SUMPAIDPENALTY) OUTSTANDING
    FROM  TAXINSTALLMENT TI1 WHERE (TI1.SUMDUETAX + TI1.SUMPAIDTAX + TI1.SUMDUEPENALTY + TI1.SUMPAIDPENALTY) > 0
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TAXINSTALLMENT TI2 WHERE YEAR(TI2.DUEDATE) BETWEEN 1980 AND   YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5  AND (TI2.SUMDUETAX + TI2.SUMPAIDTAX + TI2.SUMDUEPENALTY + TI2.SUMPAIDPENALTY) > 0
    AND TI2.FOLDERRSN = TI1.FOLDERRSN )  ORDER BY TI1.FOLDERRSN, DUEDATE DESC
```

Anyone give me idea to change to oracle .

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Its not working in oracle

Comment: Do you get a syntax error? If so, what does the message say?

Comment: ORA-00904: "DBO"."F_OPENTAX_PROPERTYROLL_FOLDER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 23

Comment: Did your database was moved from sql server to Oracle?

Comment: yes,but i want to execute in oracle  @yamny

Comment: What is it `YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5` for?

Comment: @zaratustra ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier in oracle

Comment: You use it as a predicate, if you rewrite it to oracle's `extract` function you will have an integer value, but you need to have a boolean value, so, What this string for?

Comment: @zaratustra: `YEAR(TI2.DUEDATE) BETWEEN 1980 AND YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5` means that DueDate shall be in a year from 1980 to 2009 (2014-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement uses a function F_OPENTAX_PROPERTYROLL_FOLDER(TI1.FOLDERRSN) in Schema DBO. Make sure you have installed that function in that database Schema and have granted an execution right to the user in question or to PUBLIC for that matter.

EDIT: Moreover there is no function YEAR in Oracle. You must replace it with EXTRACT: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TI2.DUEDATE)` and for GetDate(): `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)`.

Comment: for GETDATE() how to write in oracle  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM GETDATE())

Comment: Read my answer: " and for GetDate(): `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)`."